# Pri Tzadik-looking to buy

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tzadok-hakohen-lublin

I'm looking to buy Pri Tzadik from Rav Tzadok HaKohen. Any suggestions on editions and where to buy it from? I'm looking for a hard copy with no translation.

Comment: What type of version? With translation? Also are you aware that it is available on Sefaria?

Comment: Just made the question more specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a beautiful full six volume set available [here](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/pri-tzaddik-hamefoar-6-volume-set/35224)